# RGBDSLAM Crashes

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rgbd6dslam, rgbd-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the steps to install rgbdslam on ROS fuerte by installing g2o separately and changing the manifest and CMakefiles...etc.

Now when I execute rgbdslam (kinect+rgbdslam.launch) the UI pops up and the rgb and depth feeds are shown.

When I click on space or select "process" from the menu, it crashes.

I get the following error:

```
================================================================================REQUIRED process [rgbdslam-23] has died!
process has died [pid 16367, exit code -11, cmd /home/asctec/ros_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/bin/rgbdslam __name:=rgbdslam __log:=/home/asctec/.ros/log/ec9ae076-48a9-11e2-af27-000e8e31444e/rgbdslam-23.log].
log file: /home/asctec/.ros/log/ec9ae076-48a9-11e2-af27-000e8e31444e/rgbdslam-23*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
```

The log file is not actually stored so Im not sure whats going on under the hood.
Im running this on ubuntu 12.04 with ROS Fuerte

Does anyone know why this happens?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50667/rgbdslam-crashes/) by [tgaaly](https://answers.ros.org/users/2200/tgaaly/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-12-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2012-12-17**:
Hi, we are stuck at the g2o installation. Can you explain in detail what does it mean "installing g2o seperately"? using 'svn co [https://svn.openslam.org/data/svn/g2o'](https://svn.openslam.org/data/svn/g2o%27)  from open slam or 'svn [https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/vslam/trunk'](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/vslam/trunk%27)  from ros.org?

**Comment by [tgaaly](https://answers.ros.org/users/2200/tgaaly/) on 2012-12-18**:
I used https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/vslam/trunk. Then faced a problem: "certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted". I resolved this by editing the makefile & added '--trust-serve-cert' b4 '--non-interactive'. Then ran rosmake. Took a while but I was able to run-but crashed

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2012-12-18**:
Thanks. We recompiled the g2o, same error as we use the libg2o when rosmake the rgbdslam. Don't know how.. configuration incomplete error

**Comment by [tgaaly](https://answers.ros.org/users/2200/tgaaly/) on 2012-12-19**:
did u uninstall libg2o first?

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2012-12-19**:
Hi tgaaly, thanks for your help. We have made it. I wrote down all the problems encountered by us http://tianb03.blogspot.sg/2012/12/how-to-successfully-compile.html. Hope you can have a look. I hope it can help the others who want to install rgbdslam.

**Comment by [tgaaly](https://answers.ros.org/users/2200/tgaaly/) on 2012-12-19**:
no problem. Does the 3D reconstruction of rgbdslam work with you? I have tried for quite some time to get it working but there seems to be issues due to changes between openni fuerte and openni electric. The rgb & depth feeds are working fine but no 3D point clouds are shown in the top black screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

figured it out. The feature detector and extractor was set to SIFTGPU in the kinect+rgbdslam.launch file.  I do not have a GPU for this execute. This was causing a segmentation fault. I switched to SURF features and its working

---

Originally posted by [tgaaly](https://answers.ros.org/users/2200/tgaaly/) with karma: 36 on 2012-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0